Weird twist deformation with auto-rig pro IK
Here's a picture of the topology of the arm I'm trying to rig; it's a fairly simple cylinder with a couple of subdivisions:

This is for a game engine (Godot) so as per the instructions in the AutoRigPro documentation, I have this set up with 4 twist bones:

After binding the mesh with the rig, FK works fine on the arms. However, if I ever try to use FK with the arms, I get some really bizarre twisting, but only on the upper arm:

If the upper arm moves up/down it will also "snap" around and warp in the opposite direction:

Any tips to avoid this twisting? I made sure that all transformations are applied and can easily get it to happen again if I reset the transforms of the IK nodes and then move them.

Upload your file. I realize that only Auto-Rig Pro users will be able to look at it. I am one such user and I will take a look at it.
Go here to upload the file. It's the preferred way of doing so:
https://blend-exchange.com/

After looking at Auto rig pro: Knees bent backwards I think I figured it out...
My reference bones were straight:

So when auto-rig pro creates the IK poles, it creates them in the incorrect spot (forward on the Y axis, they should be up on Z):

The fix was to move the where the reference bone for the elbow is up a little bit on the Z axis, since in my model the palms are facing down and that's the direction it should bend in:

After matching the reference bones to the rig again, the pole is in the correct spot above the elbow on the Z axis:

After this, IK works as expected!

